# How to debug a .net core application in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a console application in visual studio code. It is written in C# and I am trying to build it using .NET Core 3.1. But as soon as I start debugging it says "The program '[888] MyConsoleApp.dll' has exited with code 0 (0x0)."

I have written a `console.readline()` in my code but the console window doesn't stop for it. It just opens and closes immediately.

My launch.json looks like this

```
{ 
"version": "0.2.0", 
"configurations": [ 
{ 
"name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
"type": "coreclr", 
"request": "launch", 
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/MyConsoleApp.dll", 
"args": [], 
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/",
"console": "externalTerminal",
"externalConsole": true,
"stopAtEntry": false,
"internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
"justMyCode":false,
"logging": {
    "moduleLoad": false
} 
},
{
  "name": ".NET Core Attach",
  "type": "coreclr",
  "request": "attach",
  "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
}
] 
}
```

and my tasks.json looks like this

```
{ 
"version": "2.0.0", 
"tasks": [ 
{ 
"label": "build", 
"command": "dotnet build", 
"type": "shell", 
"group": "build", 
"presentation": { 
"reveal": "silent" 
}, 
"problemMatcher": "$mscompile" 
} 
] 
}
```

When I build my project using .net 4.7.2 then the debug works fine. But, the issue is only with .net core.

Comment: Exit code 0 means that your program executed correctly. It most likely finishes without hitting the Console.ReadLine(), but you will have to show us the code in the Main function, with the ReadLine call to tell you what can be the issue (launch.json and tasks.json do not help much with this).

Comment: Perhaps is quite obvious, but have you checked if you are running the program in RELEASE mode and not in DEBUG mode?

Comment: @David I am running it in debug mode.